# Symfony2: collection form field type with data-prototype

Tags: php, symfony

I have a Team to which I would like to add players (objects of Player). I've set up the form "type" classes correctly. Here's the relevant part of my view:

```
{% for index, player in form.players %}
    <div id="template" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.players.get('prototype')) | e }}">
        <span class="title">{{ index }}</span>
        {{ form_row(player.name) }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

My problem is that data-prototype attribute doesn't include the span tag; it only contains the output of `{{ form_row(player.name) }}`. Is there a way to include the whole content of `div#template` in the `data-prototype` attribute?

Comment: I'm thinking of using a different form theme for `form.players.get('prototype')`. I'll update the post if it works.

Comment: that would be the way to go about it afaik

Comment: How did you resolve your problem here? The more general question here is, how to customize prototype? Can anyone help with that? I haven't found any consclusive information on that topic.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This was bugging me too. I customized a field type and even made simple form types with a reduced fieldset (for more complex objects), but it just didn't feel right. I've come up with a solution that should do the trick :)

First - I think your `<div id="team" data-prototype="...">` should be outside your loop.

Next, your prototype is just a form view object, so if you pass it to a template you can render fields by hand and customize the output. Note: autoescape has no effect on included content, so use 'filter escape'.

```
<div id="playerFields" data-prototype="{% filter escape %}{% include 'AcmeTeamBundle:Team:prototypePlayer.html.twig' with {'form': form.players.get('prototype')} %}{% endfilter %}">
```

Then in your prototypePlayer.html.twig, just render each field as you normally would in a form view.

```
<div>
    <span class="title">{{ form_label(form.name) }}</span>
    {{ form_row(form.name) }}
    <span class="age">{{ form_label(form.age) }}</span>
    {{ form_row(form.age) }}
    {# render whatever else you like from your Form/PlayerType class... #}
<div>
```

My template has a different data structure to your question, but it should help :)

Cheers,

Chris

---

### Deprecation Warning:

As of Symfony 2.1, `.get()` is deprecated and the above will not work. Replace `form.players.get('prototype')` with `form.players.vars.prototype` to fix this in later versions of Symfony.

Comment: I came across your solution lxion, but it seems it does not use the prototype template when rendering the form once data has been submitted and you view the same form on the next page.

Comment: @Dean, Remember that the "prototype" only serves as a template for adding new collection items on the client side. Rendering existing collection items is done server-side and is not related to the prototype. This is also valid when repopulating after a failed validation. Just render all existing collection items with your prototype template like so: 
{% for player in form.players %}
  {% include 'AcmeTeamBundle:Team:prototypePlayer.html.twig' with {form: player.vars.form} %}
{% endfor %}

Comment: Can't for the life of me get this to work. I think I've tried every possible combination now, and tried about 4 different SO post's but still no avail. If this still valid for Symfony2.5?

Comment: @Doug try setting by_reference to false

Comment: A really big thanks to @PhilippRieber, I've stumble a lot before finding this here!

Comment: BTW: I tried to get a similar result with my included template like the original prototype provided. The escape filter does not remove the spaces neither the new rows: https://gist.github.com/webdevilopers/a0b551771aa634b97a57#file-form-html-twig I tried adding twig's spaceless but still the prototype data is not in a single row: https://gist.github.com/webdevilopers/a0b551771aa634b97a57#file-data-prototype-html