# Overriding form template for repeating fields in Symfony 2

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

I have a form which contains a repeating row; I want to change the way that this row renders but in Twig I only seem to be able to override a specific row.

```
{% block _person_contacts_row_0_forename %}
{% spaceless %}
    <h3>{{ label }}</h3>
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

This works fine for the first row (id 0) but obviously doesn't work for any others.

So my question is how can I override a particular field and any repetitions of it?

Cheers,
James Bench

Comment: I found the answer I was looking for @ http://stackoverflow.com/a/9013035/855732

Answer (score 0):

use    `{{form_row(form)}}`

inside `for` loop

in your case

```
{% block _person_contacts_row_0_forename %}
{% spaceless %}
    <h3>{{ label }}</h3>

{% for user in users %}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
    {{ form_row(form) }}
{%endfor%}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

for [**for loop documentation check**](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html)

hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't change the prototype which is something I would like to use when adding additional rows.