# symfony2: Applying theme to individual field for collection type

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

Just applying a theme to form field is easy e.g.:

```
{% form_theme form _self %}

{% block _product_name_widget %}
    {{ block('field_widget') }}
{% endblock %}
```

but what if the form field is of collection type? E.g.:  `product['models'][1][comment`,
I have no ideas how to customize it. (This may be the first kind question here)

**UPDATE:** anwser here: [Symfony2: collection form field type with data-prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488831/symfony2-collection-form-field-type-with-data-prototype)

Comment: I searched around, theres already an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488831/symfony2-collection-form-field-type-with-data-prototype

Answer (score 5):

As of Symfony 2.1 (it may work as well for 2.0 but not sure) to apply theme for collection you do this way:

Lets say we have a collection of products (we have multiple Product entities)

Controller:

```
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ExampleBundle:Product');
    $products = $repository->findAll();

    $productCollection = new Products;

    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $productCollection->getProducts()->add($product);
    }

    $collection = $this->createForm(new ProductsType, $productCollection);

    return $this->render('ExampleBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array(
        'collection' => $collection->createView()
            ));
```

Your theme can look like this:

```
{% block _productsType_products_entry_name_row %}
    <div class="yourDivName">{{ block('form_widget') }}</div>
{% endblock %}
{% block _productsType_products_entry_description_row %}
    <div class="yourDivDescription">{{ block('form_widget') }}</div>
{% endblock %}
```

The trick is with "entry" where twig will do the job for you to apply above changes to each row and for each field you specify

Hope that helps!

Comment: That works like a magic, but I couldn't even find this feature in the official docs. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do with override collection_widget block:

```
{% block collection_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if prototype is defined %}
        {% set attr = attr|merge({'data-prototype': form_row(prototype) }) %}
    {% endif %}
    {{ block('form_widget') }}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock collection_widget %}
```

If you want how to customize form collection type try to look at this [Product Bundle](https://github.com/khepin/ProductBundle)

Comment: sry, I didn't find any clue in this bundle, maybe I missed something?Anyway, I found the answer mentioned above in UPDATE

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `collection_widget` theme for a single field by referencing the widget like this as well.

For example, if "categories" is a "collection" widget on a `ProductType` form, you can do this.

```
{% block _product_categories_widget %}
    {% for child in form %}
        {{- form_row(child) -}}
        <hr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```