# symfony2: index in individual form field for collection type

Tags: symfony, collections, symfony-forms

After hours of searching, I found a solution how to apply themes to individual fields for collection types here: [symfony2: Applying theme to individual field for collection type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11498487/symfony2-applying-theme-to-individual-field-for-collection-type) (thanks @TroodoN-Mike).

So a custom theme for a collection type could be:

```
{% block _author_tags_entry_label %}
    {# ... #}
{% endblock %}
```

The word "entry" replaces the row index, which works fine, but I need the Row index inside the custom block, something like {{ entry }}. Any hints?

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. I wasn't aware of the fact, that you can pass custom variables to the form theme like this:

```
{{ form_row(form.field, {'customVariable': 'anyValue'}) }}
```