# Twig : Customize specific form field in form collection

Tags: forms, symfony, collections, customization, twig

I've got a form, with an embed form, and this embed form contains a form collection.

I can customize this collection doing :

```
{% block _form_refProspect_objects_widget %}
    <div class="text_widget">
        ...
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Having my form called `form`, the embed form called `refProspect`, and the collection called `objects`. That works, but what if I want to customize only one field ?

For example, having a field called `name`, none of thise works :

```
{% block _form_refProspect_objects_0_name_widget %}

{% block _form_refProspect_objects_name_widget %}
```

Is there any solution ?

Thanks !

**EDIT :**
At the same time I would like this customization to work on the form prototype, so I can use javascript to dynamically add some.

Comment: so basically the question is how to override a particular widget-block in a collection i.e. only widget-block of the 2nd element of the collection without affecting the default one? What exactly do you want to achieve with this? styling, javascript-interaction?

Comment: That's it ! Basically how to do the same as http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#how-to-customize-an-individual-field but inside a collection.

Comment: What's the goal of this? could you describe why you need to do this ?

Comment: Well just the same goal as customizing an individual field in the documentation : modifying the template of one item without modifying the others. The only difference is this time this is not in a normal form but in a collection.

Comment: Yes is understood that ... but why do you want to change it ? what do you want to append or remove? a class, a wrapping div ...? what's the purpose? i'm asking because there might be better way of solving this without overriding this particular block - got me?

Comment: Got you ! I actually need to change few things but mainly adding a wrapping div.

Comment: As you've already stated that you want the prototype to use this changed block when adding/removing elements ... you should consider going for a pure javascript solution. The data-prototype affects all elements in the collection not just a single element.

Comment: Well, for readability and re-usability I would prefer to customize a template or something... So I can render the widget "normally", without prototype, just like a normal collection form, for the first object in the collection for example, and the other ones in JS.. I'm actually thinking about rendering it in an included custom template (with `{% filter escape %}` for the `data-prototype`)

Comment: A custom template for `data-prototype` will involve adding custom javascript logic which defeats your previous argument for a non-javascript "solution".

Comment: The Javascript using the prototype is always kind of custom, isn't it ? What I meant is that I'd like to use the same template for the prototype and for a normal rendering, so I don't duplicate any code..

Answer (score 1):

you can create your custom field type and add your logic to it.

a pretty good example would be [How to Create a Custom Form Field Type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html)

For example i use a custom CKEditor field type to make text fields as WYSIWYG editors. I used [this bundle](https://github.com/trsteel88/TrsteelCkeditorBundle). You could check the source code to see how it works.

Comment: Well yeah I guess it would work, but that's a bit getting around the problem... Aren't we supposed to be able to easily custom our forms with Twig ? A custom field would be for a really new field, not just customizing an existing one...

Comment: well it depends on what customization you want to add. If you really want a prototype field you could use anywhere this is the way to go.

Comment: I agree this is a good solution (plus, it's pretty easy to create a custom field type in Symfony2), but that's not really what I was looking for.. But I guess this is more clean than including a template as said in this post : http://stackoverflow.com/a/9013035/2452521 ?

Comment: the include template solution would also work. just try both wyas and see which suits you better, which is increase load time less, etc.