# Symfony 3 | custom data-prototype displayed two times

Tags: forms, symfony

I try to display my custom data-prototype for a CollectionType. I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9013035/1821417).

This is what I have:

```
    {{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'class': 'form-horizontal'}}) }}

    <div class="form-group">
    {{ form_label(form.answers, "Answers", {'label_attr': {'class': 'col-sm-2 control-label'}}) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.answers) }}

    <div id="mybundle_add_answers"
         data-prototype="
         {% filter escape %}
         {% include 'MyBundle:Form:prototype_answers.html.twig' with {'form': form.answers.vars.prototype} %}
         {% endfilter %}">
    </div>
    <a href="#" id="add_answer" class="btn btn-primary">Add</a>
</div>

    {{ form_rest(form) }}
    {{ form_end(form) }}
```

This is working but, because of form_rest, it displays my data-prototype (mybundle_add_answers) a second time at the end of the form.

It seems that nobody have this problem so What did I do wrong here / forget? I use Symfony 3.0 maybe this is related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a way to do what I wanted with custom data-prototype. I don't know if this is because of Symfony 3 that I have a double widget.
Anyway I did what I wanted with custom collection_widget. If anyone is interested in : https://gist.github.com/cowlby/1294186
And if someone find an answer for this "double" widget problem, I'm still curious to know.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the exact same problem.

After spending a day searching the web for this problem, I ended up simply not using `{{ form_rest(form) }}` and `{{ form_end(form) }}`. In my template I added the csrf token manually by using `{{ form_widget(form._token) }}`, then closed the `</form>` manually, because in my case that's all `form_rest` and `form_end` did.